# How to remove leading dash from filenames in Bash

Tags: bash, rename

I have a directory with files like:

```
-001.jpg
-002.jpg
...
-100.jpg
```

and I would like to remove the leading dash of each one.

I have tried:

```
rename -vn 's/^-//g' *
```

But I get:

```
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: .
Unknown option: j
Unknown option: p
Unknown option: g
Unknown option: 0
Unknown option: 0
```

and so forth…

How can one play the trick?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303929/handling-names-with-leading-dash-in-bash-shell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-` is treated as an option for `rename` command.

You can use `rename` like this:

```
rename -vn -- 's/^-//' *
```

Comment: And there is no need to use `g` (global), since we're only removing `-` at the start.

Comment: Thanks! Haven't know this!

Comment: Btw, is there a specific meaning for double dash "--" in bash?

Comment: `--` separates options with arguments.

Answer (score 3):

With just shell parameter expansion, no external tools:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.jpg; do mv -- "$f" "${f#-}"; done
```

The `nullglob` shell option makes sure that `*.jpg` doesn't expand to anything if it doesn't match any files; `"${f#-}"` expands to the filename stored in `f` minus the leading hyphen.

`mv --` is required to prevent the filename to be interpreted as an option to `mv`.

---

Not all versions of `mv` understand `--` as the delimiter of options. It is, as fas as I can see, for example not required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html). A more portable version would be to use

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "./$f" "./${f#-}"; done
```

instead. Hat tip to [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) for pointing it out.

Comment: Not all versions of `mv` understand `--` as a delimiter. It's more portable to use `mv "./$f" "./${f#-}` (the `./` prefix prevents misparsing, but otherwise doesn't affect it).